# iOS version specific Default.png?

Tags: ios, ios6, default.png

Now that iOS 6 has come out and tweaked some control appearances, my Default.png family no longer matches the updated appearances.

If I update the appearance for iOS 6, however, the Default.png family will no longer match iOS 5.

Is there a way to provide different launch images for iOS 5 vs iOS 6?

Adding Default-568h@2x.png does not fix this problem; the problem is that Default.png and Default@2x.png must either show iOS 5 or iOS 6 screens, and they do not look the same.

Comment: No there is not.  The launch image is outside the control of your program.  Unless Apple implements this logic into SpringBoard, you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, borrrden. I was hoping that logic already existed and I'd just overlooked the documentation for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in one of my apps that there was a small difference in position of one of the standard control types (captured in my launch image) between iOS 5 and iOS 6. I chose to use the new iOS 6 screenshot as the launch image, even though that causes a slight visual shift when launched on iOS 5. Virtually everybody will upgrade, so I'm not really concerned about the shift only appearing on iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6's launch image is named "Default-568h@2x.png"

Comment: No, that's the one for the iPhone 5 and new iPod touch. Of course these devices run iOS 6 but they're not the only ones that do.

Comment: I believe you're confusing the iPhone 5 and iOS 6. iOS 6 runs fine on a standard (iPhone 3GS) or Retina (iPhone 4/4S) display. My problem is I have to make Default.png and Default@2x.png match iOS 5 or iOS 6, resulting in an incorrect launch image on one or the other.